# escaping PHP in css background image, or problem in css syntax?

Tags: php, css

edit: found the solution. after asking around a lot, it seems that the problem lied on both. At first, it wont show because of double quotes. I removed that, and the browser is now supposed to render it just fine. Now the reason it didnt show up is because `width` and `height` were not set. I just set an arbitrary amount of both despite my CSS code, now I can see them lurking round the corner.

this could have been real simple but I could not get how this one works. I am building a slider and getting images from database using PHP.

The problem is the images wont display.

I am using this code to display the image thru CSS:

```
$output .= '<div class="overlay-image" style="background-image: url("'.$image.'");"></div>
```

Everything totally works, from down to up, except that part where the image wont display.
I even set the CSS for `overlay-image` such as

```
.overlay-image {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I removed that `background-image` style, and used `img` under it instead. It DOES show the image successfully albeit being screwed out of position (no design yet of course)

```
 <img src="'.$image.'">
```

The value of the `$image` contains the folder itself. the page im editing is the `index`) For example, if you print it out it will say `uploads/img.jpg`

I opened up the inspector and it showed:
[image]

I also tried this approach and it didnt work. Now I'm really confused about what is exactly the problem.

```
$image = $row['image'];
$image-bg-style = "background-image: url('".$image."'); ";
```

Comment: You use double quote inside a double quote, and i think your path for the image is wrong

Comment: I also removed the doublequotes inside the style, so it looks like `<div class="overlay-image" style='.$image.'></div>` still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you've run out of different quote marks:

```
$output .= '<div class="overlay-image" style="background-image: url("'.$image.'");"></div>';
```

You have these quotes all nested together:

- The PHP single quotes `'<div ...url("'` and `'");"></div>'`
- The HTML attribute quotes, `style="...;"`
- The CSS quotes, `url("...")`

Note that the HTML and CSS quotes use the same character, so *the browser doesn't know which is which*. It's interpreting them like this:

- An HTML attribute, `style="background-image: url("`
- Some more HTML attributes with whatever PHP echoes from `$image`
- A stray `");"` on the end, which is probably just discarded

What you need to do is escape the CSS quotes appropriately to fit inside HTML - `"` becomes `&quot;`:

```
$output .= '<div class="overlay-image" style="background-image: url(&quot;'.$image.'&quot;);"></div>';
```

Comment: It still didnt work for me, did exactly just that.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out: you're nesting double quotes inside double quotes:

```
$output = ' style=" background-image: url("'.$image.'") " '
                  ^                       ^          ^  ^
```

produces

```
style=" background-image: url( "_someurl_" ) "
```

interpreted by the browser as

```
style="background-image: url( "

_someurl_" ) "
```

What you want is **single** quotes around `_someurl_`:

```
style=" background-image: url( '_someurl_' ) "
```

But you can't use them straight ayway because then you're confusing PHP, as your string is already quoted with single quotes:

```
$output = ' style=" background-image:url( '_some_url_' ) " ';
          ^                               ^          ^     ^
```

will give a parse error.

So the trick is to use single quotes **disguised** as something that PHP does not recognize as single quotes, but the browser does. For that, you can replace the single quotes inside the string with

- its HTML Entity equivalent `&apos;`
- `chr(39)`, being the ascii charcter `'`

Your code would the be:

```
$output.= '<div class="overlay-image" 
           style="background-image: 
           url(&apos;'.$image.'&apos;);"></div>
```

or

```
$output.= '<div class="overlay-image" 
           style="background-image: 
           url('.chr(39).$image.chr(39).');"></div>
```

Comment: I tried both, still did not work. I opened up inspector and this is what is showed to that code
`<div class="overlay-image" style="background-image: url('uploadedimg/61bfd1ac51a6b5.87619245.jpg');"></div>`


In contrast, the working `img` shows
`<img src="uploadedimg/61bfd1ac51a6b5.87619245.jpg">`

Comment: Ah. Remove the apostrophes in the url part of the style tag. so `style="background-image: url(uploadedimg/61bfd1ac51a6b5.87619245.jpg);"

Comment: After removing the apostrophes, they still dont show up.

using `apos&` this is the result on the inspector
`<div class="overlay-image" style="background-image: url('.$image.');"></div>`

and using `chr(39)`
`<div class="overlay-image" style="background-image: url(.chr(39).$image.chr(39).);"></div>`

Comment: Try hardcoding the url in the code (replace `$image` with the actual link) and see if it shows up then. Otherwise something else is wrong.